# Page taking time in loading. Also used lazy loading but doesn't work?

Tags: performance, optimization

There are number of logo images and many are shown under show more button. But all are getting loaded at a time. Due to page speed decreases. I have used lazy load plugin but still is taking time on page refresh or loading

Comment: Without a link to the page it is impossible for us to help you diagnose this.

Comment: this is the link - https://www.retailcore.in/customers

Answer (score 0):

Your site's speed can depend on too many factors. The most important one is server's speed. Contact your hosting provider and ask them to check the issue and to increase the PHP memory limit. Then deactivate all plugins to free memory. After that try to install a caching plugin, there are several caching tutorials and different caching plugins. Try more than one.